# How to find a binary name with only the prefix?

Tags: bash, scripts, ls, clang, tail

Context: I have a bash script that generates a windows import library from a MinGW cross-compiled DLL. As part of the build process, it runs `llvm-dlltool-6.0`, because that happens to be the specific version of that tool that's installed when I `sudo apt-get install -y clang` (as of May 2019). However, I'm not sure if this will be the version in the future, and I'd really rather not tie the script to the version of clang.

This appears to be a deficiency in the llvm tools package. There are many tools that are suffixed and not symlinked to the tool name (I have both `llvm-dlltool-6.0` and `llvm-dlltool-8` in `/usr/bin/`).

The right way to fix this for my system on its lonesome is just to make the symlinks using `update-alternatives`. However, I'd rather not require that everyone running the build script do this, nor do I want to continually need to fix the Dockerfile every time clang gets updated.

Is there a good way (in a bash script) to find the highest-version-suffixed binary that starts with `llvm-dlltool` that exists on the PATH? I can `ls /usr/bin/llvm-dlltool-* | tail -n1`, but I can't be sure every user has it installed in that location (also I'd like to respect symlinks if a user does actually have `llvm-dlltool` symlinked).

Comment: Note that `/usr/bin/llvm-dlltool-* | tail -n1` will fail horribly when `llvm-dlltool-10` is released.   An alphanumeric sort is not good enough for version numbers: sorting version numbers requires special care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all the programs in the $PATH variable, search for the ones you want with grep and then sort numerically with the following command:

```
version=$(echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n} | while read line; do find "$line" -name "llvm-dll*"; done | grep llvm-dll | sed 's/[^0-9]*//' | sort -n | tail -n 1)
whereis $(echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n} | while read line; do find "$line" -name "llvm-dll*"; done | grep llvm-dll | grep $version) | sed 's/.*: \//\//'
```

The whereis command will give you the user's path to that command. Finally cut will only ouput the actual location of said command. I pulled the version number first so that the sort command can process it seperately. Otherwise, llvm-dll-10 would be sorted before llvm-dll-9

Edit: Added ls flags to prevent errors.

Edit: Made it space compatible.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/246819)

Comment: alternative: `find ${PATH//:/ } -name "llvm-dll*" | …`

Comment: Cool; thanks! Only issues is that this makes `llvm-dlltool-6.0` sort higher than `llvm-dlltool-8` because 60 > 8, but it's an easy fix

Comment: This doesn't work if you have spaces in any folders in your path (thanks WSL...)

Comment: So you could always do something like this: echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n} | while read line; do find "$line" -name "llvm-dll*"; done | ...